# Some bars are black when trying to use individual colors

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm using dc.js to draw my charts, and trying to give different color to the bars.

Some bars are black instead of the colors I requested. How do I get the chart to use the color array?

This is the code

```
var keyColorCodes;
keyColorCodes = dc.config.defaultColors();

bar.colors(d3.scaleOrdinal().domain(d3.keys(keyColorCodes)).range(d3.values(keyColorCodes)));
bar.colorAccessor(function(d) { 
  return d.key;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain of your `scaleOrdinal` should be an array containing the set of values which your `colorAccessor` will return. Right now you are pulling the set of indices of the `dc.config.defaultColors()`.

One easy way to get the set of values is to map your `group.all()` through your `colorAccessor`:

```
.domain(speedSumGroup.all().map(d => d.key))
```

Also, [d3.values](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#values) is intended to be used with associative arrays, i.e. objects. It has no effect when applied to an ordinary array.

Here is a general way to do it, which should work in most cases:

```
  chart
    .colorAccessor(d => d.key)
    .colors(d3.scaleOrdinal()
              .domain(speedSumGroup.all().map(d => d.key))
              .range(dc.config.defaultColors()));
```

[image: bar chart with colors]

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/9vkcmn2z/5/).